# Index out of bound exception while creating Arraylist of Arraylist in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

**What I am trying to do:**

- I have a list of 3 students
- I am trying to create a group among them (So first group will have 2
  students and second group will have one student)

---

*Here is the code:*

**FragDispGroupBlocksVM.kt**

```
class FragDispGroupBlocksVM @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private var mStudentList: MutableList<StudentModel> = ArrayList()


    constructor(studentList: MutableList<StudentModel>) : this(){
        mStudentList = studentList
        initStudentGroups()
    }

    fun initStudentGroups() {

        var mStudLstPartn : ArrayList<ArrayList<StudentModel>> = ArrayList()


        var partitionedList = GroupingUtils.partitionIntoSubGroups(mStudentList,2)

        val mList = partitionedList.filterIsInstance<ArrayList<ArrayList<StudentModel>>>()

        mList.forEachIndexed{i,element ->
            mStudLstPartn.add(element[i])
        }



        // mPartitionedList.postValue(mList);
        Timber.i("")
    }

}
```

**GroupingUtils.kt**

```
class GroupingUtils {
    companion object {
        fun <T> partitionIntoSubGroups(
            members: Collection<T>,
            maxSize: Int
        ): MutableList<List<T>> {
            val res: MutableList<List<T>> = ArrayList()
            var internal: MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
            for (member in members) {
                internal.add(member)
                if (internal.size == maxSize) {
                    res.add(internal)
                    internal = ArrayList()
                }
            }
            if (internal.isNotEmpty()) {
                res.add(internal)
            }
            return res
        }
    }
}
```

**StudentModel.kt**

```
data class StudentModel(
    @SerializedName("role")
    val role: String,
    @SerializedName("_id")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("kneuraId")
    val kneuraId: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    var isPresent: Boolean = true
): Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest!!.writeString(role)
        dest.writeString(id)
        dest.writeString(firstName)
        dest.writeString(lastName)
        dest.writeString(kneuraId)
        dest.writeString(email)
        dest.writeByte(if (isPresent) 1 else 0)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<StudentModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): StudentModel {
            return StudentModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<StudentModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**What is happening ::**

The line below has 3 elements

```
private var mStudentList: MutableList<StudentModel> = ArrayList()
```

It is working till line

```
val mList = partitionedList.filterIsInstance<ArrayList<ArrayList<StudentModel>>>()
```

It is crashing in line below loop in second iteration

```
 mList.forEachIndexed{i,element ->
            mStudLstPartn.add(element[i])
        }
```

**Log:**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.cnx.project.grouping.viewModels.FragDispGroupBlocksVM.initStudentGroups(FragDispGroupBlocksVM.kt:30)
```

**Questions:**

- Why there is a index out of bound exception
- How to make a Array list of Arraylist similar to java
- How to resolve the error

---

[Edit]

**I have 2 elements**
[image]

Comment: what are you looking to achieve with the part that loops mList? doesn't partitionedList already has the groups you need ?

Comment: @MohamedMohsin ... I am trying to add all elements of `mList` to `mStudLstPartn`

Comment: if I may ask, doesn't `partitionedList` already have the students in groups of two? isn't that what is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is where the error happens:

```
    mList.forEachIndexed { i, element ->
        mStudLstPartn.add(element[i])
    }
```

You are iterating through `mList`, but are using the index from `mList` to access item from `element`.

You have a `mList` like this `[[a, b], [c]]`, so its elements are these:

at index 0: `[a, b]`

at index 1: `[c]`

When your `forEachIndexed` iterates for the second time, `element` only has one item (which is `c` at index **0**), but you try to access `element[1]`, which, of course, throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because there is no second element.

Comment: ....`at index 1:` I have the element ... I have posted a image. please check the edit part of question. How to resolve this, should I loop in a different way

Comment: Correct, you have 1 element, which is found at index 0.
At index 1 you access the **second** element in the array, which does not exist.
I'll update the answer to make it more specific and thus more clear.

Comment: Ok, then how to add all elements of `mList` to `mStudLstPartn`

Comment: `mStudLstPartn = mList.flatten()`

Comment: Using this will make three elements .... but As per the question I am trying to achieve `Array list` of `Arraylist` ... meaning first element of `mStudLstPartn` should have a `arrayist` of 2 elements and the second item must have `array list` of 1 element

Comment: By the looks of it, it already works.
In `mList` you have what you want to store into `mStudLstPartn`.
If this is the case, just do `var mStudLstPartn = GroupingUtils.partitionIntoSubGroups(mStudentList,2)` and make sure you have the right types everywhere.

Comment: It did solve the error thanks, ..so ill mark this as accepted ... I have some queries ..Ill formulate as a new question

Answer (score 0):

The problem will come form here

```
 mList.forEachIndexed{i,element ->
     mStudLstPartn.add(element[i])
 }
```

We can see `mList` is a array list and it is containing many other elements. Each element is a list too. `i,element ->` means i is index of element in mList.

For resolve this problem you need add all items of element to mStudLstPartn by traveling all items of element.

Answer (score 0):

**safe Call**

```
<List>.getOrNull()

exa:
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(list.getOrNull(0)) // 1
println(list.getOrNull(2)) // 3
println(list.getOrNull(3)) // null

val emptyList = emptyList<Int>()
println(emptyList.getOrNull(0)) // null
```

linking: you have seehttps://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-null.html